# What is the mistake in my solution to find roots of a parabola?

Tags: roots, conic-sections

The parabola is,

$\frac{1}{2}g{{t}_{t}}^{2}+u{t}_{t}-2H=0$

By the way, $u=\sqrt{\frac{3gH}{2}}$. I have found the discriminant as below,

$\Delta=b^2-4ac$

$\Delta=u^2-4(\frac{1}{2}g)(-2H)$

$\Delta=u^2+4gH$

$u^2=\frac{3gH}{2} \Rightarrow \Delta=\frac{3gH}{2}+4gH=\frac{11gH}{2}$

Let's find roots,

${{t}_{t}}_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$

${{t}_{t}}_{1,2}=\frac{-u\pm\sqrt{\frac{11gH}{2}}}{g}$

The variable ${{t}_{t}}$ is a variable of time. Time can not be negative, so I use $+$ sign.

${{t}_{t}}=\frac{-u+\sqrt{\frac{11gH}{2}}}{g}$

But, when I put this in the parabola, I can't get $0$ as result. Is there any mistake?

*important:* $g$ and $H$ are constants. So, $u$ as well a constant.

Comment: Why can't time be negative? Why would forcing the addition in the numerator necessarily lead to a positive result (unless you also know *g* to be positive)?

Comment: $g$ and $H$ are positive. If the time would be negative, that would mean I'm going to examine the motion of the object before it has started to move. So that, the time must be positive. I know that here is not for discussing physics. You should better check my question once more.

Comment: Your solution is correct. Perhaps you made an arithmetic error in the verification step?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Blue. I have checked my arithmetic in the verification step like 3 or 4 times but I must have an error that I still can't aware of it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both solutions produce $0$ in $f$.
\begin{align*}
f&\left( \frac{-u + \sqrt{\frac{11gH}{2}}}{g} \right)  \\
    &= \frac{g}{2} \left( \frac{-u + \sqrt{\frac{11gH}{2}}}{g} \right)^2 + u \left( \frac{-u + \sqrt{\frac{11gH}{2}}}{g} \right) - 2H  \\
    &= \frac{g}{2} \left( \frac{ \left( -u + \sqrt{\frac{11gH}{2}} \right)^2}{g^2} \right) + u \left( \frac{-u + \sqrt{\frac{11gH}{2}}}{g} \right) - 2H  \\
    &= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\left( -u + \sqrt{\frac{11gH}{2}} \right)^2}{g} + u \left( \frac{-u + \sqrt{\frac{11gH}{2}}}{g} \right) - 2H \cdot \frac{g}{g}  \\
    &= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{u^2 -2u\sqrt{\frac{11gH}{2}} + \frac{11gH}{2}}{g} +  \frac{-u^2 + u \sqrt{\frac{11gH}{2}}}{g} - \frac{2gH}{g}  \\
    &= \frac{\frac{1}{2} u^2 -u\sqrt{\frac{11gH}{2}} + \frac{11gH}{4}}{g} +  \frac{-u^2 + u \sqrt{\frac{11gH}{2}}}{g} - \frac{2gH}{g}  \\
    &= \frac{\frac{1}{2} u^2 -u\sqrt{\frac{11gH}{2}} + \frac{11gH}{4} -u^2 + u \sqrt{\frac{11gH}{2}} -2gH}{g}  \\
    &= \frac{\frac{-1}{2} u^2 + \frac{11gH}{4} - 2gH\cdot\frac{4}{4}}{g}  \\
    &= \frac{\frac{-1}{2} \frac{3gH}{2} + \frac{11gH}{4} - \frac{8gH}{4}}{g}  \\
    &= \frac{\frac{-3gH}{4} + \frac{11gH}{4} - \frac{8gH}{4}}{g}  \\
    &= \frac{0}{g}  \\
    &= 0  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Similarly for the other root.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I saw what was my mistake by your answer. It's funny to forgot the opening of $(a-b)^2$. I thought it is $(a-b)(a+b)$. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @n3pixowe: Told ya! ;)